# Getting 'ISO C90' error not allowing VLA while compiling with C99

Tags: c, compilation

My compile line:

```
gcc -Wextra -Wall -Wvla -std=c99 StringChange.c -o StringChange
```

My program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 51

char switchChar(char c)
{
    if((c>='A')&&(c<='Z'))
        {
        c = c + 32;

        }
     if((c >='a')&&(c<='z'))
        {
        c = c - 32;
        }
     if(c>'5')
        {
           c = 56;

        }
     if (c<'5')
        {
           c = 48;

        }
    return c;
}

int main(void) 
{   
    char temp;
    int i=0,j=0;
    char stringInput[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    printf("Please enter a valid string\n");
    scanf("%s",stringInput);

    while(stringInput[i]!='\0')
        {
            i++;
        }
    char newString[i];
    for(j = 0;j<i;j++)
    {
        temp = switchChar(stringInput[j]);
        newString[j] = temp;
    }
    printf("\"%s\"", stringInput);
    printf("->");
    printf(  "\"%s\"",newString);        

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling I keep getting the error 'ISO C90 forbids variable length array newString' even though I'm compiling with C99 in the command line (the solution  in other stackexchange questions).

Would appreciate your help and any additional comments.
Thank you

Comment: a warning would be ok (see answer already given) but it shouldn't be an error. With gcc 4.9.3, I only get a warning. What version are you using?

Comment: You asked for that warning by using `-Wvla`.

Comment: a warning is not an error, he wrote, he got an error ...

Comment: I compiled with: `cc -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -std=gnu99 -c "%f"  -I.`  where the `%f` is replaced with the name of the file being compiled.  The result was two warnings about conversion from `int` to `char`, but the VLAs compiled with no problem.

Comment: in function: `switchChar()` the `if` statements, other than the first should be `else if`  otherwise the code will not do as you seem to expect

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the `%s` format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is only less than the length of the input buffer to avoid buffer overflow.  Suggest: `#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 50`  ... char stringInput[MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];  if( 1 != scanf( "%" MAX_STRING_LENGTH "s", stringInput ) ) { perror( "scanf for input string failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: when declaring `newstring[]` be sure to clear it, so the resulting string will be terminated with a NUL byte I.E.: `char newstring[i+1] = {'\0'};`   Amongst other problems, the posted code is making the array `newstring[]` 1 byte too short and not terminated.  Otherwise, this line: `printf(  "\"%s\"",newString);` will be accessing beyond the end of the `newstring[]` array, looking for a NUL byte, which will be undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Answer (score 4):

The `-Wvla` option provides that diagnostic. From [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> -Wvla
>      Warn if variable length array is used in the code.  -Wno-vla prevents the -Wpedantic warning of the variable length array.

Obviously the error message is a bit misleading. But it's mainly used for older code ( before C99) to VLA use where VLAs are supported to as an extension. Since you are compiling in C99 mode, you can simply drop the `-Wvla` from your commandline option.